# Citus co-location with jsonb relation

Tags: database, postgresql, relationship, jsonb, citus

I'm trying to co-locate tables in a cluster using citus, but the relationship is mentioned in the tables in a json scheme, as in the example below:

```
TABLE person(
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);

TABLE event(
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    resource jsonb NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

and the relation is mentioned in the resource column, as well as in this example:

```
resource{
    ...,
    subjetc{
        resource_type: person,
        reference: uuid
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create the distributed tables so that they are co-located through this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is currently not possible. You would have to add a column like `subject_id` that has the same content as `resource->>subject->>reference` to the event table to make this work. This does duplicate the data a bit, but it's the only way that is currently supported.

Comment: Is it possible to automate this process, from copying the subject to the column, before the data is distributed to the nodes?

Comment: You might be able to use a TRIGGER for this, but I'm not sure. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html